# Using Category ID in Permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I use category ID in wordpress permalinks?
I want to use it on permalinks.
For example it looks so now;

```
x.com/category/general
```

I want it to show so;

```
x.com/ {some tags} 123
```

We write `%post_id%` for post IDs. But what must we write for Category IDs?

Answer (score 1):

We can define or set permalink in different format so, in admin section in **permalink setting** option. select the **default option** and gives category inside **category base** ex: **category** input box

and save the changes. so, You can get that permalink using **[image: get_permalink()]**

Comment: yes I want to to so, but what must I write for category ID?

Comment: for example, we write %post_id% for Post Ids.. But what about category ID?
what must we write for it?